# Admissible box constraint for a quadratically constrained linear program

Tags: linear-programming, quadratic-programming

I am looking at a real-world resource allocation problem that is cast as a quadratically-constrained linear program of the form

$$
\max\langle f,x\rangle
$$
subject to
$$
\begin{aligned}
m \leq\,\, & x \leq M, \\
A\cdot x & \leq b, \\
A_{eq}\cdot x & = b_{eq}, \qquad\text{and} \\
\langle x,Q\cdot x\rangle & \leq \alpha.
\end{aligned}
$$

It is a small problem, that is, $x\in\mathbb{R}^{55}$, and it can be solved in much less than a second using Matlab's $\verb|fmincon|$ to obtain an optimal solution $x^*$. The question is the following: is there an "intelligent" (read: systematic/efficient; again, hacks are welcome) way to determine an admissible box constraint of the form
$$
\tilde{m}\leq x*\leq \tilde{M}\ ? \qquad(1)
$$
That is, if $B$ is the region described by the box constraint (1) and $F$ is the feasible region of the original problem, then it should be the case that
$$
B\subseteq F.
$$
It is fine if $B$ has empty interior, as long as the relative interior with respect to the affine subspace that contains $B$ is not empty.

To provide some context, the components of the optimal solution $x^*$ are communicated to production departments that operate *independently* and $B$ represents allowable deviations from their targets. Let me point out that, as is implicit in the description of the problem, the original constraints are hard constraints and it is not meaningful to violate them; i.e., to have a box $B$ around $x^*$ that extends beyond the feasible region.

**Question:** Any pointers to the literature, high-level hints to the right direction, or quick and dirty approaches to the following problem will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your problem statement is somewhat confused- is $x^{*}$ the fixed optimal solution to the QP?  In that case, you're presumably looking for a box $B$ that contains $x^{*}$, but all of $B$ is also feasible.  In general, there may be no nontrivial $B$ that does this (that is, the largest such set you can form contains only the point $x^{*}$.)  Do you want to place bounds on the quadratic objective within your box?  Do you have an objective for B that you want to optimize (e.g. volume, minimum side length)?

Comment: Do you perhaps want to minimize the maximum value of your original objective over a set $B \subseteq F$?